# Magento 2 - REST API - How to create order for customer with admin token

Tags: magento2, orders, rest-api, token

I'm working on an app for Magento store. and I want to create an order for customers with my admin token.

I found 2 ways:

1. To get the customer credentials (user name and password) and create a queue - But I can't get all the users credentials.
2. create a guest order but I didn't find a way to add the customer’s id only email.

so the order is not linked to the customer's orders history.

is there a way to create an order for customer with admin token? and link to order to the customer profile?

Thanks!